# What is the point of logging.config.dictConfig() if it does not affect existing loggers?

Tags: python, logging

Configuring a logger using the APIs provided by `logging.Logger` as shown in `b.py` configures existing loggers. Configuring logging with `logging.config.dictConfig()` does not configure existing loggers as shown by `a.py`.

## `*.py` files

```
~/bar                                                                                    
▶ tail -n +1 *.py
==> a.py <==
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging_config = dict(
    version = 1,
    handlers = {
        'h': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'}
    },
    root = {
        'handlers': ['h'],
        'level': logging.DEBUG
    }
)

dictConfig(logging_config)

logger.debug("This is a test")

==> b.py <==
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

logger.debug("This is a test")
```

## I/O

```
~/bar                                                                                    
▶ python -m a

~/bar                                                                                    
▶ python -m b
This is a test
```

If a library creates a logger before `logging.config.dictConfig()` is set up, the logger will not be configured properly. How do libraries handle this? Do they expect a logging configuration be passed to them? Do they simply avoid creating loggers during import?

Answer (score 2):

`logging.config.dictConfig()` does affect the configuration of existing loggers. However, `dictConfig()` will disable existing loggers by default unless `disable_existing_loggers = False` is defined in the dictionary passed to `dictConfig()` according to [`16.7.2.1. Dictionary Schema Details`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details).

Comment: Then I don't really get it. By default, `disable_existing_loggers = True`. To be sure I forced it to True and each time I have the same result. I make sure to import logging after all the modules that create loggers. I define the root logger so that no DEBUG or INFO are displayed on screen. But it doesn't work, I still have INFO on screen. 

My dict have:
`"loggers":
    {
    "root":
        {
        "level":"NOTSET",
        "handlers":["console", "file"],
        },
    },
"disable_existing_loggers":True,`

Comment: @Autiwa you need to set the value to **`False`**

Comment: Dude @ShipluMokaddim , It doesn't work like that in dictConfig anymore. It works in fileConfig but in case of dictConfig, you need to specify explicitly in the config dict itself. like in the example here - https://gist.github.com/alanbriolat/d5ffe608b56c948533c6

Comment: @codingbruh In your link `disable_existing_loggers` is set to `False` in `dictConfig`. That's what I exactly mentioned in the comment. Or, did I miss something?

Comment: Hey @ShipluMokaddim I was saying that you can't pass `disable_existing_loggers` as functional argument dude.

Comment: @codingbruh Please read the first 2 comments in the thread. Autiwa was passing a dict in dictConfig. There was the config pasted as well. and I said, to set the value to False. That's the only change I mentioned. Why would you assume more changes then?